# Rails—count of all records in db?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a very snowballing program that creates a whole heap of records (from different models).

I want to delete the main record, and make sure all the other records associated have also been deleted.

Is there a way to simply count all records in my DB, regardless of what table? Then I can create everything, trigger the main delete, then check if there's anything left in the DB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Rails.application.eager_load!
ActiveRecord::Base.subclasses.sum(&:count)
```

Comment: As a note on large databases with a lot of active writes this can take a consderable amount of time.

Comment: Tried this, the second line only returned: 
`[ApplicationRecord(abstract), ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration(version: string)]`

Comment: @Mirror318, it sounds like you have a non-default subclass between `ActiveRecord::Base` and your models, e.g. `class MyBase < ActiveRecord::Base`. Find that subclass and call `MyBase.subclasses.sum(&:count)`.

Comment: Oh right, I had a base class called `ApplicationRecord`, so this worked: `ApplicationRecord.subclasses.sum(&:count)`